# forward_list::splice_after( const_iterator pos, forward_list& other, const_iterator i ) functionality

Tags: c++, list, c++11, splice, forward-list

I'm reading different interpretations of the way this function should work.

[cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/forward_list/forward_list/splice_after/) says that this function should "move the element directly AFTER i".
Yet [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/splice_after) says that it splices the element AT i.
MSvisual studio agrees with cplusplus.com. However what is actually the correct behaviour? I tend to think moving "after i" is more logical (& doesn't take N time to find the preceding node).

(PS: no forward-list tag?)

Comment: I've fixed the cppreference.com page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

23.3.4.6

```
void splice_after(const_iterator position, forward_list& x, const_iterator i);
void splice_after(const_iterator position, forward_list&& x, const_iterator i);
```

> Effects: Inserts the element following i into *this, following position, and removes it from x. The
> result is unchanged if position == i or position == ++i. Pointers and references to *i continue to
> refer to the same element but as a member of *this. Iterators to *i (including i itself) continue to
> refer to the same element, but now behave as iterators into *this, not into x.

Comment: The standard is defective in that case; `*i` should read `*++i` in the above, and the aside *(including `i` itself)* should be removed.

Comment: I've submitted a draft DR to the isocpp.org discussion group: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/vE---WC2SuI%5B1-25%5D